# Knowledge graphs, logic and categories recommendation

Tags: logic, graph-theory, category-theory, type-theory

I recently started to be more interested about "classical AI" and in particular about knowledge graphs/ontologies. I was looking for a modern (written after 2015 if possible) and highly mathematical book on this subject. In particular, I would love if the book used formalisms from logic and category theory (or a subset/superset :) of these).

Thx!

Comment: Why suppose that category theory [in the mathematical sense] would be specifically relevant? Categories in the mathematical sense and categories in the sense relevant of formal ontologies are surely quite different things.

Comment: @petersmith actually there are category theory (in mathematical sense) based descriptions of ontologies https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olog. The information is mostly on papers, was cuorious if there is a book that uses this formalism